Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (1205 > 512)
I am using ROBERTa model for predicting sentiment for aspect. When I execute in Colab or VScode. I am getting the "Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (1205 > 512). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors". I am using the tokenize_roberta method to pass the text into the model. I have tried various mechanisms to truncate the input ids and attention_masks to a length <= to 512 but it still warning error.
I am attempting to perform the truncation at this line:
    def tokenize_roberta(self, text, max_len):
        encoded = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            text,
            add_special_tokens=True,  
            max_length=max_len,  
            padding='max_length',  
            return_attention_mask=True,  
            truncation=True  
        )

        return np.array(encoded['input_ids']), np.array(encoded['attention_mask'])

the line for input_ids and attention_masks
            if isinstance(tokenizer, Tokenizer4Roberta):
                input_ids, attention_masks = tokenizer.tokenize_roberta("<s> " + text_left + " " + aspect + " " + text_right + " </s>", 512) 

the model ROBERTa below:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class RoBERTa(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, roberta, opt):
        super(RoBERTa, self).__init__()
        self.roberta = roberta
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(opt.dropout)
        self.dense = nn.Linear(opt.bert_dim, opt.polarities_dim)  

    def forward(self, input):
        outputs = self.roberta(input_ids=input[0], attention_mask=input[1])

        pooled_output = outputs.pooler_output

        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)

        logits = self.dense(pooled_output)
        
        return logits

Why token indices sequence length > 512

How do you call tokenize_roberta?
